# presentModalViewController not working

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

here's my code:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableView" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
//[self setView:[vc view]];
```

If I call it, nothing happens. However, if I change it to:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TableView" bundle:nil];
//[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
[self setView:[vc view]];
```

The view appears just fine (without the transition, of course).
What am I doing wrong? Is there anything special you have to take care of when initializing the view controller? I tried to copy as much as possible from Apple's examples, but I can't get this to work...

Thanks for any input!

-- Ry

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can only present modal view controllers from controllers that have already been shown onscreen (usually through a UINavigationController or UITabBarController). Try creating a UINavigationController, pushing a viewController to it, and *then* presenting your modal controller. There's a starter project in Xcode that shows how to create a UINavigationController-based flow if you're unfamiliar with it.

One other thing to note: if you haven't pushed the view controller onto a UINavigationController, the .navigationController property will be nil, and messaging it will have no effect.

Comment: Meh. Isn't there an easier way to do this? I don't really want to create a UINavigationController just to be able to slide up a view...
Thanks for your answer, though!

Comment: You don't have to create a nav controller to do this, but you're referencing it here. If just have a view controller, you can just use IT to present a modal view controller (ie, get rid of the ".navigationController" if your code example above. You will have to add your viewController's view to your main window to make this work.

Comment: Another thing for people browsing here: You might need to move code for presenting a VC from viewDidLoad: to viewDidAppear:animated:. I presume this is because the view hasn't been shown onscreen in viewDidLoad.

Comment: Hi @Ben Gottlieb and Tom H and all. I have a problem with UIModalViewController full screen in ipad. I need your help. This is my question can you help me? Please see this link to know my problem...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413263/uimodalpresentationfullscreen-not-working-in-ipad-landscape-mode

Comment: @TomH, thanks for that suggestion. It helped me a lot - indeed model view controller must be presented inside viewDidAppear, not viewDidLoad!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem while attempting to show a modal view over another modal view. Ben's answer is correct, and can be implemented like so:

```
@interface FirstView: UIViewController {

    UIViewController *firstView;
}

- (IBAction)showOptionsView:(id)sender;

@end
```

In the main view class:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    firstView = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
    [firstView setView:self.view];
    [firstView setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical];
}

- (IBAction)showOptionsView:(id)sender {
    OptionsView *optView = [[OptionsView alloc]initWithNibName:@"OptionsView" bundle:nil];

    if(firstView != nil) {
        [firstView presentModalViewController:optView animated:YES];
        [optView release];
}
```